# unexpected behaviour of ACL linux

Tags: linux, bash, acl

Found the strangest behaviour in using acl using the `d` switch:

Test with the `d:` in the setfacl commando

```
create directory: mkdir /var/tmp/tester
create three users: useradd userA -d /tmp etc…
remove the other permission of the directory: chmod 750 /var/tmp/tester
grant acl permissions for userA: # file: setfacl -md:u:userA:rwx var/tmp/tester/
grant acl permissions for userB: setfacl -m d:u:userB:rx /var/tmp/tester
grant acl permissions for userC(not really needed): setfacl -m d:u:userC:rwx /var/tmp/tester
list the acl of the directory: getfacl /var/tmp/tester

       # owner: root
        # group: root
        user::rwx
        group::r-x
        other::---
        default:user::rwx
        default:user:userA:rwx
        default:user:userB:r-x
        default:user:userC:---
        default:group::r-x
        default:mask::rwx
        default:other::---

Become userA and navigate to the tester dir: ''su - userA cd /var/tmp''/tester
```

Result: -bash: cd: /var/tmp/tester: Permission denied

Now same test but not using the `d:` in my acl setfacl commando

```
create directory: mkdir /var/tmp/tester
create three users: useradd userA -d /tmp etc…
remove the other permission of the directory: chmod 750 /var/tmp/tester
grant acl permissions for userA: # file: setfacl -m u:userA:rwx var/tmp/tester/
grant acl permissions for userB: setfacl -m u:userB:rx /var/tmp/tester
grant acl permissions for userC(not really needed): setfacl -m u:userC:rwx /var/tmp/tester
list the acl of the directory: getfacl /var/tmp/tester

       # owner: root
        # group: root
        user::rwx
        group::r-x
        other::---
        default:user::rwx
        default:user:userA:rwx
        default:user:userB:r-x
        default:user:userC:---
        default:group::r-x
        default:mask::rwx
        default:other::---

Become userA and navigate to the tester dir: ''su - userA cd /var/tmp''/tester
```

Result: Success!?

is this expected behaviour?
Why does the getfacl does not show any difference in the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d:` is short for `default:` and specifies the *default* ACLs for a directory, not the real ACLs. From `man 5 acl`:

```
OBJECT CREATION AND DEFAULT ACLs
     The access ACL of a file object is initialized when the object is created
     with any of the creat(), mkdir(), mknod(), mkfifo(), or open() functions.
     If a default ACL is associated with a directory, the mode parameter to
     the functions creating file objects and the default ACL of the directory
     are used to determine the ACL of the new object:

     1.   The new object inherits the default ACL of the containing directory
          as its access ACL.

     2.   The access ACL entries corresponding to the file permission bits are
          modified so that they contain no permissions that are not contained
          in the permissions specified by the mode parameter.
```

So, yes: it's normal that you observe different behavior when (not) using `d:`.

However note that the output from `getfacl` you have posted is wrong: in the second case (when not using `d:`) you should have some lines prefixed with `user:userA`, `user:userB`, `user:userC` instead of the lines prefixed with `default:`. Here's a simpler example:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ setfacl -m u:nobody:rx a
$ setfacl -m d:u:nobody:rx b
$ diff -u <(getfacl a) <(getfacl b)
--- /dev/fd/63  2016-03-12 11:10:20.032239216 +0100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2016-03-12 11:10:20.024239117 +0100
@@ -1,9 +1,12 @@
-# file: a
+# file: b
 # owner: andrea
 # group: andrea
 user::rwx
-user:nobody:r-x
 group::rwx
-mask::rwx
 other::r-x
+default:user::rwx
+default:user:nobody:r-x
+default:group::rwx
+default:mask::rwx
+default:other::r-x
```

Comment: @Sander: with `d` you are setting the *default* ACL, not the real ACL. Read the man page excerpt I've posted to know more about default ACLs

Comment: You are right that the output i posted was not correct, i had some probs pasting my text on this site. So my second question is not a correct question. But what about my first. I create a directory, chmod it, set acl giving userA full permission and is unable to access the /var/tmp/tester dir when using the acl commando with d:?. To me its strange access to a directoy is not granted using the default acl switch making the acl i set useless, and not using the d switch makes the acl works as I intended. I hope you see what i mean when you use my commandos

Comment: @Sander: again, be sure to read the man page excerpt. The default ACL is applied only when a new object (file, directory, fifo, device) is created. It does not affect at all the permissions of the directory itself

Comment: thank you andrea, i see the man, was not aware of this, if i want to have the acl applied to current files and dirs and future files i should execute two acl commands, one for the default, one for the current.